# How to limit the effect of a validator (asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I would like to ask, how do I limit the effect of a validator across an aspx page? For example, if I have a validator for a textbox within the ContentPlaceHolder, how I make it such that the validator only affects buttons within the ContentPlaceHolder itself, and **not** affect buttons in the header/footer placed in the MasterPage?

Comment: Search for validation groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create [validation groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx) which help you classify the controls for your exact requirement. Just use the same group for your button and the controls and you are good to go!!